# Process substitution =(list) in middle of argument

Tags: zsh

How can I use `=(list)`-style process substitution in the middle of an argument?

This works:

```
% echo =(echo)
/tmp/zshxxxxxx
```

So does this:

```
% echo =(echo):works
/tmp/zshxxxxxx:works
```

But this does not:

```
% echo broken:=(echo)
zsh: missing end of string
```

Notably, this also works:

```
% echo works:<(echo)
works:/proc/self/fd/11
```

The problem is `=(list)` can only stand at the beginning of arguments.  Quoting from the ZSH manual:

> The expression may be preceded or followed by other strings except
>   that, to prevent clashes with commonly occurring strings and patterns,
>   the last form [this is =(list)] must occur at the start of a command
>   argument, and the forms are only expanded when first parsing command
>   or assignment arguments.

I have a tool that accepts an argument of the form `format:filename`, and I need to use a real file, not a pipe, so I cannot use `<(list)`.  What is a reasonably simple and readable solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to "buffer" the process substitution.

```
% echo fixed:${:-=(echo)}
fixed:/tmp/zshxxxxxx
```

Comment: But then, the substituted command is parsed very differently. Mine is `cat $d/some-config.json $d/some-config-$env.json | jq -s add | tee /dev/stderr`, and it seems I would have to quote at least each dollar, minus, and pipe.

Comment: Yes, you would.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to use the previous answer for a makefile, and it was not so trivial so here is my solution.

The initial problem is that with MinGW, the command line length is quite limited and it will get truncated in case of a very long object list, so I need to use the *@file* syntax for gcc, which allow to provide the arguments in a file.

```
SHELL := /bin/zsh

myprog.exe: very.o long.o list.o of.o obj.o files.o ...
        gcc -o $@ @$${:-=(<<< \"$^\")}
```

There is an alternate solution by using an anonymous function called immediatly :

```
myprog.exe: very.o long.o list.o of.o obj.o files.o ...
        () { gcc -o $@ @$$1 } =(<<< "$^")
```