zsh: how to pass =() to curl
Similar to how <(list) process substitution can be used in
curl -XPOST example.com/foo -F file=@<(<<<data)

how can I use =(list) process substitution in the same command?
I tried
curl -XPOST example.com/{foo,bar} -F file=@=(<<<data)
curl -XPOST example.com/{foo,bar} -F file=@=(print data)

but these give me
zsh: parse error near `)'
zsh: unknown file attribute: i


One possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632968

Try escaping the @; it's meant as a literal character in the argument to curl.

Use quotes, if you need to treat special characters literally.

@Gairfowl it works! nice hack!
